# Is a for...each loop the best way to extract a List of primitives from an IQueryable of custom objects?

Tags: linq-to-sql

For example if I had an IQueryable of Person objects and each Person had an Age ID and I wanted to make another query that selected all rows from a table that contains an integer ID that was in this IQueryable of IDs...

Could I use something like this?

```
List<int> AgeList = new List<int>();

foreach(Person p in Persons)
{
    AgeList.Add(p.Age);
}

var ageStats = from a in db.Ages
                where AgeList.Contains(a.Age)
                select a;
```

Or what would be a better way so I didn't need to loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to perform a join. Since you mentioned that `Persons` is an `IQueryable`, is it coming from the database as well?

Either a `join` or `SelectMany` (which translates to a join in LINQ to SQL) should suffice.

**Join:**

```
var ageStats = from a in db.Ages
               join p in db.Persons on a.Age equals p.Age
               select a;
```

**SelectMany:**

```
var ageStats = from a in db.Ages
               from p in db.Persons
               where a.Age == p.Age
               select a;
```

Comment: Good point...I assumed the ages were in memory...but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: Well in the context of the example I am not looking up the ages until they select multiple persons, so I have to wait for user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
List<int> AgeList = Persons.Select(p => p.Age);
```

However, even tho the [msdn page for .Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) does not say much, I'm pretty sure `.Select` still is a loop, so you won't really gain any performance by writing it like that

Comment: Persons.Select(p => p.Age) does not return a List<int> (or execute anything in a loop for that matter). If you want a list, you've got to do .ToList(). Until then, it's just a non-enumerated enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ageStats = from a in db.Ages
               where Persons.Select(p => p.Age).Contains(a.Age)
               select a;
```